# Rotate Between divs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to create a slider that would have 3 divs, and when I click on a button, it would move the left most div out, and bring in a new div that wasn't visible originally from the right. I would like to do this without using [Content Carousel](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/)...

It works on the first click, but after that the divs get all mixed up and don't switch in and out correctly, is there a better way to implement this? or is there something wrong with my logic in the code?

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aqesiw/73/edit)

also here is my code:

```
function toggleDiv(total, idprefix) {
for (var i=1; i<total+1; i++) {
    var j = i-1;
    if (i==1) {
        document.getElementById(idprefix+i).id = 'last';
    } else if(i==total) {
        document.getElementById(idprefix+i).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(idprefix+i).id = idprefix+j;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(idprefix+i).id = idprefix+j;
    }        
}

document.getElementById('last').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('last').id = idprefix+total;
```

}

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? There are dozens of slider/carousel plugins out there. You can check out mine at https://github.com/ozzyogkush/jquery.contentSlider if you like

Comment: hey thanks! I like your slider, but what I need is a little different. I don't need all the functionality, more like something simpler, you know?

Comment: [A simple one](http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/). Bootstrap's [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) is also fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick 'n' mucky solution using jQuery:

```
function toggleDiv() {
    $('.slider div:last').show();
    var $firstElement = $('.slider div:first').hide();
    $('.slider').append( $firstElement );
}
```

Best off using one of the myriad of carousels out there though as they will give you nice animations as well.